# Proof of " dyadic rational numbers are dense in $\mathbb R$"

Tags: real-analysis

The set $\left\{\frac{m}{2^n}:m \in \mathbb Z,n \in \mathbb N^+\right\}$ is called the set of dyadic rational numbers,show that the set is dense in $\mathbb R$.
The proof is as follows:

> Consider two arbitrary real numbers $a,b$ with $a< b $,By the Archimedean Property there exists $n \in \mathbb N$ such that $$0< \frac{1}{n} <b-a \;\;\text{ which implies} \;\; 0<\frac{1}{2^{n}}<\frac{1}{n}<b-a$$
> Thus we have $1<b2^n-a2^n$,As the distance between $a2^n$ and $b2^n$ is is greater than $1$, there exist
> $m \in \mathbb N$ such that $a2^{n}<m<b2^{n}$

I don't understand where does such $m$ come from,why such $m$ should exists?

> which implies that $a<\frac{m}{2^{n}}<b$,since $a,b$ were arbitrary so the claim is proved.

Comment: The relevant claim is "if $L>M$ are two real numbers such that $L-M>1$ then there is an integer $k$ with $L>k>M$".  To prove it, let $\lfloor M\rfloor $ denote the greatest integer less than or equal to $M$ and let $k=1+ \lfloor M\rfloor$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any interval $(a,b)$ with $b-a>1$ contains an integer.
Indeed, let
$$m=\max(\{k\in\mathbb{Z}: k\leq a\}),$$
then
$$a<m+1<\underbrace{a}_{\geq m}+\underbrace{b-a}_{>1}=b.$$
Therefore the integer $m+1$ belongs to the interval $(a,b)$.